# Como fazer um hanking de scores de um jogo em javascript

Tags: javascript, game

tenho que gerar uma tabela com os cinco primeiros scores armazenados em um objeto json. Creio ter muitas maneiras de se fazer isso, mas o que eu consegui até agora foi filtrar os scores por nível e por user:

```
let users = [{
                "id": 1,
                "username": "Gustavo",
                "pwd": "20",
                "scores": [{
                        "id": 2,
                        "score": 5,
                        "level": "hard"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "score": 10,
                        "level": "easy"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "score": 15,
                        "level": "easy"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "username": "Elisa",
                "pwd": "10",
                "scores": [{
                    "id": 5,
                    "score": 150,
                    "level": "easy"
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "username": "Tati",
                "pwd": "2",
                "scores": [{
                        "id": 5,
                        "score": 20,
                        "level": "easy"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "score": 2,
                        "level": "easy"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "score": 10,
                        "level": "easy"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

```
`$ranking = users.map(users => ({ users: users.username, scores: users.scores.filter(scores => scores.level === "easy") }));`
```

[image: não sei se esse resultado é necessário para listar, a parir daí, o username e o score, mas eu imaginei que eu teria que criar algo como $topFiveLevel[] = "cada posição recebe o username seguido do score", porém, não consigo fazer essa iteração... se alguém souber como, ou tiver uma solução mais adequada. Obrigado!]

Comment: Desculpe-me a insensibilidade, mas exatamente qual o problema?

Comment: Então, eu não sei como apresentar o resultado na tabela (a tabela dinâmica eu consigo montar), mas não consigo colocar o nome e o score, por isso eu disse na pergunta que pode ter uma maneira mais direta de fazer, sem ter que salvar o nome e o score num array pra depois ordenar, pra depois mostrar na tabela. Fazer esse filtro eu consegui, não sei se é possível ver isso na imagem que eu coloquei, só aparece os nomes e o objeto "scores" com apenas os valores cujo nível é "easy", mas como listar isso é que eu não consigo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução ficou um pouco extensa mas imagino que compreenda uma boa parte do problema.

```js
/**
 * @typedef Score Pontuação de um usuário
 * @property {number} id ID da pontuação do usuário
 * @property {number} score Pontuação do usuário
 * @property {string} level Dificuldade
 */

/**
 * @typedef User
 * @property {number} id ID do usuário
 * @property {string} username Nome do usuário
 * @property {string} pwd ???
 * @property {Array<Score>} scores Lista de pontuações do usuário
 */

/** @type{Array<User>} */
const users = [
  {
id: 1,
username: "Gustavo",
pwd: "20",
scores: [
  {
    id: 2,
    score: 5,
    level: "hard",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    score: 10,
    level: "easy",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    score: 15,
    level: "easy",
  },
],
  },
  {
id: 2,
username: "Elisa",
pwd: "10",
scores: [
  {
    id: 5,
    score: 150,
    level: "easy",
  },
],
  },
  {
id: 3,
username: "Tati",
pwd: "2",
scores: [
  {
    id: 5,
    score: 20,
    level: "easy",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    score: 2,
    level: "easy",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    score: 10,
    level: "easy",
  },
],
  },
];

const highestToLowestSortingStrategy = (a, b) => b - a;
const lowestToHighestSortingStrategy = (a, b) => a - b;

/**
 * Filtra os dados de uma determinada lista de
 * usuários e ordena suas pontuações através
 * de uma dificuldade
 *
 * @param {Array<User>} users Lista de usuários
 * @param {string} difficulty Dificuldade utilizada para o filtro da pontuação
 * @param {(a: any, b: any) => number} sortingStrategy Estratégia de ordenamento de scores
 * @returns Retorna a lista filtrada de usuários
 */
const filterScoresByDifficulty = (
  users,
  difficulty,
  sortingStrategy = highestToLowestSortingStrategy
) =>
  users
.map(({ scores, ...user }) =>
  scores
    .filter((score) => score.level === difficulty)
    .map((score) => ({
      ...user,
      ...score,
    }))
)
.reduce((list, next) => [...list, ...next], [])
.sort((a, b) => sortingStrategy(a.score, b.score));

const filteredEasyScoresHighestToLowest = filterScoresByDifficulty(
  users,
  "easy"
);
const filteredHardScoresLowestToHighest = filterScoresByDifficulty(
  users,
  "hard",
  lowestToHighestSortingStrategy
);

console.log(filteredEasyScoresHighestToLowest);
console.log(filteredHardScoresLowestToHighest);
```

Comment: Eu agradeço pelo seu código, mas esse resultado eu já havia conseguido, que é selecionar por nivel, o que eu não consigo fazer é listar o par nome/pontuação, porque se fosse uma pontuação para cada usuário, um for in resolveria. o problema é que teria que associar o nome a cada pontuação e num for, para cada posição deveria registrar o nome e o valor de uma pontuação e num segundo registro o mesmo nome e uma outra pontuação: tipo, [0]Gustavo  100pts, [1]Gustavo 200pts, [2]Elisa 500pts, Elisa 250pts..

Comment: Sem problemas, código corrigido agora.

Comment: Eder, me perdoe, revendo seu resultado eu percebi que é diferente do que havia conseguido. cada posição tem o nome, o nível e a pontuação. Agora eu consigo selecionar por nível e ordenar do maior pro menor. Obrigado!